# Android: Interpolator not working on custom dialog

Tags: android, animation

I have created a dialog with an enter animation from top.
like that:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
    Window dialogWindow = getWindow();
    assert dialogWindow != null;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialogWindow.getAttributes();
    DisplayMetrics dm = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    lp.width = dm.widthPixels;
    lp.height = DisplayUtil.dip2px(mContext, 300);
    dialogWindow.setAttributes(lp);
    dialogWindow.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    dialogWindow.setWindowAnimations(R.style.DropDown);
...
}

<style name="DropDown" mce_bogus="1" parent="android:Animation">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/dropdown_in</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/dropdown_out</item>
</style>
```

the animation is ok but the interpolator doesn't work .
this is the "dropdown_in" animation i define

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 2):

this might be late, but can help anyone who search for it.

```html
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"android:shareInterpolator="true"
>
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%p"
        android:toYDelta="0" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your are turning an Activity into a Dialog. In this case, there is a conflict with Activity's animation. You may want to override Activity's animation instead. Please update your code, using overridePendingTransition(R.style.DropDown, R.style.DropDown);

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...

    overridePendingTransition(R.style.DropDown, R.style.DropDown);

    Window dialogWindow = getWindow();
    assert dialogWindow != null;
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialogWindow.getAttributes();
    DisplayMetrics dm = mContext.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    lp.width = dm.widthPixels;
    lp.height = DisplayUtil.dip2px(mContext, 300);
    dialogWindow.setAttributes(lp);
    dialogWindow.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
    dialogWindow.setWindowAnimations(R.style.DropDown);
...
}
```

Comment: it isn't a activity ,i just extends Dialog.and i had used super(context, R.style.DropDown); in constructor function.

Comment: it doesn't work anymore.  Dialog doesn't has the overridePendingTransition().

Comment: In that case, you can check two solutions:
1. Use this to create an instance of your Dialog: Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DropDown);

2. Using an Activity and apply Theme Dialog for it. Then, you can use above code